# Script returns ModuleNotFoundError despite installing simple-smartsheet

Tags: python, pip, conda, smartsheet-api

I am running Anaconda with Python 3.7, and I want to use the **simple_smartsheet** module in the script.  I installed Smartsheet with

```
!pip install simple-smartsheet
```

and it shows success (see below), but when running my script, I get a `ModuleNotFoundError`. *Why can it not find the module?*

Here is the script:

```
import logging
import csv
import os
import sys
from pprint import pprint
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date

logging.basicConfig(filename='rwsheet.log', level=logging.INFO)

SheetID="Smartsheet Sheet Name"

# simple_smartsheet is a more user friendly tool to allow for everyday transactions with
# Smartsheet's API.  Believe it or not, it is much better than what Smartsheet provides.
from simple_smartsheet import Smartsheet
from simple_smartsheet.models import Sheet, Column, Row, Cell, ColumnType

# Add SMARTSHEET_ACCESS_TOKEN to environment .bashrc.  It holds the token assigned
# from Smartsheet to access remotely.
TOKEN = "*****************"

# Name of the Smartsheet being updated
SHEET_ID = SheetID

smartsheet = Smartsheet(TOKEN)

print("SHEET_ID: ", SHEET_ID)

sheet = smartsheet.sheets.get(SHEET_ID)
```

After running, here is the exact error that it emits:

```
Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-3-e2d38a84d6b8> in <module>
     13 # simple_smartsheet is a more user freindly tool to allow for everyday transactions with
     14 # Smartsheet's API.  Beleive it or not, it is much better that what Smartsheet provides.
---> 15 from simple_smartsheet import Smartsheet
     16 from simple_smartsheet.models import Sheet, Column, Row, Cell, ColumnType
     17 

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'simple_smartsheet'
```

---

This is the output from the install command:

```
!pip install simple-smartsheet

Requirement already satisfied: simple-smartsheet in c:\users\cabbs\anaconda3\envs\p37workshop\lib\site-packages (0.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: attrs in c:\users\cabbs\anaconda3\envs\p37workshop\lib\site-packages (from simple-smartsheet) (19.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: requests in c:\users\cabbs\anaconda3\envs\p37workshop\lib\site-packages (from simple-smartsheet) (2.24.0)
Requirement already satisfied: cattrs in c:\users\cabbs\anaconda3\envs\p37workshop\lib\site-packages (from simple-smartsheet) (1.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: mypy-extensions in c:\users\cabbs\anaconda3\envs\p37workshop\lib\site-packages (from simple-smartsheet) (0.4.3)
Requirement already satisfied: aiohttp in c:\users\cabbs\anaconda3\envs\p37workshop\lib\site-packages (from simple-smartsheet) (3.7.2)
Requirement already satisfied: marshmallow<4,>=3 in c:\users\cabbs\anaconda3\envs\p37workshop\lib\site-packages (from simple-smartsheet) (3.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<3,>=2.5 in c:\users\cabbs\anaconda3\envs\p37workshop\lib\site-packages (from requests->simple-smartsheet) (2.10)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\users\cabbs\anaconda3\envs\p37workshop\lib\site-packages (from requests->simple-smartsheet) (2020.6.20)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<4,>=3.0.2 in c:\users\cabbs\anaconda3\envs\p37workshop\lib\site-packages (from requests->simple-smartsheet) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3!=1.25.0,!=1.25.1,<1.26,>=1.21.1 in c:\users\cabbs\anaconda3\envs\p37workshop\lib\site-packages (from requests->simple-smartsheet) (1.25.9)
Requirement already satisfied: async-timeout<4.0,>=3.0 in c:\users\cabbs\anaconda3\envs\p37workshop\lib\site-packages (from aiohttp->simple-smartsheet) (3.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: yarl<2.0,>=1.0 in c:\users\cabbs\anaconda3\envs\p37workshop\lib\site-packages (from aiohttp->simple-smartsheet) (1.6.2)
Requirement already satisfied: multidict<7.0,>=4.5 in c:\users\cabbs\anaconda3\envs\p37workshop\lib\site-packages (from aiohttp->simple-smartsheet) (5.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: typing-extensions>=3.6.5 in c:\users\cabbs\anaconda3\envs\p37workshop\lib\site-packages (from aiohttp->simple-smartsheet) (3.7.4.2)
```

Comment: How are you running the script? We need to see evidence that the script is actually executing in the environment (**p37workshop**) that you imply it should be. For example, consider adding a `import sys; print(sys.prefix)` to show where it runs. Please edit the question to include this info, as it is essential to question.

Comment: import logging
import csv
import os
import sys

print(sys.prefix)

Answer (score 0):

I wound up scrapping the p37workshop environment and ran under the Anaconda default.  It ran with no problems!  I was trying to run the Python 3.7 version which is why I created the p37workshop.  However, I just learned I can use the latest Python version so I don't need to keep trying to get the p37workshop to work.

Thank you for taking a look.  The more I've been working with simple_smartsheet, I am floored on how much it makes this soooo much easier interfacing with Smartsheet.